# This iPhone is synced with another iTunes library........do you want to erase this iPhone

Tags: itunes, iphone

How to copy songs from my PC to iphone without erasing my iphone?

itunes giving this error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to connect the iPhone to the machine you originally synced it with and check the manually manage music and videos option on the summary screen, in iTunes.

[image: see how to manually manage music]

After that you'll be able to connect your iPhone to any iTunes library and drag and drop media straight on to the device, in the column on the left of iTunes.

[image: see how you can add music when manually manage music is selected]

You can also try to back up your iPhone on the new machine, by right clicking on the device in the left pane of iTunes and selecting backup.
Note: If you sync with the new machine, music will not transfer from your phone to the computer, and you will have the same problem if you try to perform a sync with the original machine!

Comment: Is there anything I can do if I no longer have access to that original synced computer?

Comment: "You have to connect the iPhone to the machine you originally synced it with" - that's hardly helpful. What if you're not able to do that. It could have crashed or been stolen. Stupid Apple, creating unnecessary restrictions!